# How to create custom blog page for custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-type, wordpress

I have created custom post type, and right now all posts, including custom posts, are running through the same main blog loop.

What I want to do is to display custom posts in different template blog page. Its working for single custom post type as custom_post_type-single.php only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well,

I assume that your permalink settings are set to the post name. first refresh your permalink settings. custom post types has it's own archive page. www.yoursite.com/{your_post_type_slug}

you dont have to create any page for that. That will work automatically after you registered the custom post type.

so write your custom blog code on archive-{your_post_type_slug}.php file. this file must be in the root of your theme folder.That code will affect in www.yoursite.com/{your_post_type_slug}

for single view of your custom post type posts use single-{your_post_type_slug}.php file. this file also must be in your theme root.

hope this will help